# Why does Crystal Reports do a Cartesian product of details sections?

Tags: crystal-reports

Say I have the 3 tables below and create joins from table 1 to table 2 and from table 1 to table 3 on the UserID field.  If I create two details sections, one with table 2 data and the second with table 3 data, crystal will produce 8 rows of results as if it is doing a cartesian product of Tables 2 & 3.  I expected it to just output 4 rows.  The solution is to use sub-reports, but I'm wondering why does it do this?

Table 1

```
UserID Name
1      'John Smith'
```

Table 2

```
GameID UserID Score
1      1      50
2      1      60
```

Table 3

```
CarID  UserID  Make
1      1       Acura
2      1       Tata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal does this because where the 2 other tables (games, cars) are unrelated.  The userid field sends a request to each of the tables for information.  Both tables then send the information back to it, and crystal shows the information that was retrieved.  If you added criteria to the report like max(carid) and max(gameid) you would get a single answer for both, you could also try just a max(carid) to see if you would still get all of the gameid's (this depends on how your joins are created)

Answer (score 1):

You get four rows based on how you have joined the tables (2 rows from [Table 2] X 2 rows from [Table 3])

You get four more rows because you have two 'Details' sections.

Games and Cars have no logical relationship, so you should move one of those tables to a correlated sub-report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one sub report per details section and use following two queries in each of the sub report

select USERID, Name ,Score, Make
FROM [Table 1] inner join [Table 2] on  [Table 1].userID=  [Table 2].USERID

select USERID, Name , Make
FROM inner join [Table 3] on  [Table 1].userID=  [Table 3].USERID

Comment: Hi, yes I'm aware that the fix is to use sub-reports, I'm just wondering why they are necessary in this instance.